CGAL Customed AABB_tree face a question which can not read memory in AABB_tree's feild 'm_primitives' when left function which construct the tree
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <CGAL/Simple_cartesian.h>
#include <CGAL/AABB_tree.h>
#include <CGAL/AABB_traits_3.h>
 
 
 
typedef CGAL::Simple_cartesian<double> K;
 
 
// custom point type
struct My_point {
    double m_x;
    double m_y;
    double m_z;
 
    My_point(const double x,
        const double y,
        const double z)
        : m_x(x), m_y(y), m_z(z) {}
};
 
// custom triangle type with
// three pointers to points
struct My_triangle {
    My_point *m_pa;
    My_point *m_pb;
    My_point *m_pc;
 
    My_triangle(My_point *pa,
        My_point *pb,
        My_point *pc)
        : m_pa(pa), m_pb(pb), m_pc(pc) {}
};
 
// the custom triangles are stored into a vector
typedef std::vector<My_triangle>::const_iterator Iterator;
 
// The following primitive provides the conversion facilities between
// the custom triangle and point types and the CGAL ones
struct My_triangle_primitive {
public:
 
    // this is the type of data that the queries returns. For this example
    // we imagine that, for some reasons, we do not want to store the iterators
    // of the vector, but raw pointers. This is to show that the Id type
    // does not have to be the same as the one of the input parameter of the
    // constructor.
    typedef const My_triangle* Id;
 
    // CGAL types returned
    typedef K::Point_3    Point; // CGAL 3D point type
    typedef K::Triangle_3 Datum; // CGAL 3D triangle type
 
private:
    Id m_pt; // this is what the AABB tree stores internally
 
public:
    My_triangle_primitive() {} // default constructor needed
 
    // the following constructor is the one that receives the iterators from the
    // iterator range given as input to the AABB_tree
    My_triangle_primitive(Iterator it)
        : m_pt(&(*it)) {}
 
    const Id& id() const { return m_pt; }
 
    // utility function to convert a custom
    // point type to CGAL point type.
    Point convert(const My_point *p) const
    {
        return Point(p->m_x,p->m_y,p->m_z);
    }
 
    // on the fly conversion from the internal data to the CGAL types
    Datum datum() const
    {
        return Datum(convert(m_pt->m_pa),
            convert(m_pt->m_pb),
            convert(m_pt->m_pc));
    }
 
    // returns a reference point which must be on the primitive
    Point reference_point() const
    { return convert(m_pt->m_pa); }
};
 
 
 
typedef CGAL::AABB_traits_3<K, My_triangle_primitive> My_AABB_traits;
typedef CGAL::AABB_tree<My_AABB_traits> Tree;
 
Tree m_tree{};

int buildTree()
{
  My_point a(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    My_point b(0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
    My_point c(0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    My_point d(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
 
    std::vector<My_triangle> triangles;
    triangles.push_back(My_triangle(&a,&b,&c));
    triangles.push_back(My_triangle(&a,&b,&d));
    triangles.push_back(My_triangle(&a,&d,&c));
 
    // constructs AABB tree
    m_tree=Tree(triangles.begin(),triangles.end());
    m_tree.build();
return 0;
}
int method1()
{
  return 0;
}
int main()
{
  buildTree();
  method1();
}

I tried to save the constructed AABB_tree as a field resource.But After leaving the function 'buildTree()', I can no longer access the memory in the AABB_tree's field 'm_primitive' when going into fuction 'method1()'. How can I solve this issue, and can 'shared_data' help? If so, please provide me with some advice.

The problem is that the vector triangles should not be local to builtTree function. Because as soon as you leave buildTree() it is deleted. Even if you activate caching, you would get invalid primitive_ids (iterators).
